# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'time')at addStore (script.js:80:17) at HTMLDivElement.onclick (index.html:70:68

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'time')
at addStore (script.js:80:17)
at HTMLDivElement.onclick (index.html:70:68

I tried creating a new firebase it worked but the problem came again

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code, you attempted to access the 'time' property of an undefined object, which resulted in the error. Look for any places in your code where you are referring to an undefined object, and correct them. Furthermore, make sure you are connecting to the correct Firebase database instance and that your Firebase settings are accurate.